# Java - set HTTP only cookie to root path

Tags: java, cookies

I'd like to set a cookie which is both HTTP only and to the root path.
For HTTP only cookie I use:

```
cookie.setPath("; HttpOnly;");
```

And for root path:

```
cookie.setPath("/");
```

How can I merge the two?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot merge the 2 but you can do:

```
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to support < Servlet 3.0 (setHttpOnly was added on Servlet 3.0)